# how to insert a boxplot in a worksheet

Tags: r, excel, plot, xlsx

I want to include boxplots in a workscheet created in R

[here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/r-xlsx-package-a-quick-start-guide-to-manipulate-excel-files-in-r#add-a-plot-into-an-excel-worksheet) I found a useful way under "Add a plot into an Excel worksheet"
its using the addPicture funtion
but `sheet <-createSheet(wb, sheetName = "boxplot")` doesnt work in the lybrary xlsx and XLConnect won't install.

I tried to modify it to this:

```
addWorksheet(wb,  "boxplot")
    sheets <- getSheets(wb)
```

and now i get this error

```
> Error in envRefInferField(x, what, getClass(class(x)), selfEnv) :   
> ‘getNumberOfSheets’ is not a valid field or method name for reference
> class “Workbook” 
> 5. stop(gettextf("%s is not a valid field or method name for reference class %s", 
>     sQuote(field), dQuote(thisClass@className)), domain = NA) 
> 4. envRefInferField(x, what, getClass(class(x)), selfEnv) 
> 3. wb$getNumberOfSheets 
> 2. wb$getNumberOfSheets 
> 1. getSheets(doc)
```

Did i mess up my library's that getSheets calls a function with invalid references?
Or is there an other way to save boxplots in a worksheet without the XLConnect pakage

Comment: What do you mean by: `sheet <-createSheet(wb, sheetName = "boxplot") doesnt work fot the lybrary xlsx and XLConnect won't install.` 
Are you saying that both `xlsx` and `XLConnect` are not installed? (I 'd recommend strongly against using XLConnect anyways)? So what library **are** you using to work with excel files?

Comment: i was using XLSX but it seemed to me the 'createSheet' function was in XLConnect. So i tried to install is (tho i didn't realy feel like ') This seems to have messed up the functions in XLSX that did work before. openXLSX seems to do the job for now, but i rather restore xlsx. Do I just reinstall it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `xlsx` does not seem to work for you, you could try the very useful package `openxlsx` (**no** Java dependecy, very fast, very versatile, though it only supports working with '.xlsx' files):

```
install.packages("openxlsx")

wb <- openxlsx::createWorkbook()
openxlsx::addWorksheet(wb, "a_sheet_with_a_plot")
plot(cars)
openxlsx::insertPlot(wb, sheet = "a_sheet_with_a_plot", width = 10, height = 8, xy = NULL, startRow = 1,
                     startCol = 1, fileType = "png", units = "in", dpi = 300)
openxlsx::saveWorkbook(wb, file = "excel_file_with_a_plot_sheet.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: XLSX did work before i guess i messed up by trying to install XLConnect.. your solution works but can i somehow undo the damage on XLSX?

Comment: Try uninstalling XLConnect. I might have had a similar issue once, which i resolved by removing anything related to XLConnect. Also you could try to call the function with explicit namespace, i.e. `xlsx::createSheet()`

Comment: The problem seems to be in rJava

Comment: yea, Java is really struggling playing nice with R. I highly suggest using the `openxlsx` solution suggested above instead of `xlsx` or `XLConnect` (as long as you are fine with only working with .xlsx files (no .xls))